# Removing an added list item using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a task manager, where you add tasks when a user clicks add after inputting their task, and a button to remove is available right next to the added task. My problem is I'm not sure on how to program the button to remove the added task.

This is my code:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="addtask">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Input Today's Tasks" size=100px class="data" id="texter">
        <button onclick="addLi()">Add</button>
        <span class="priority">
        <button style="width: 3.5px; height: 30px;" class="less" data-less><span class="green"></span></button>
        <button style="width: 3.5px; height: 30px;" class="median" data-median><span class="orang"></span></button>
        <button style="width: 3.5px; height: 30px;" class="important" data-important><span class="reder"></span></button>
        </span> 
    </div> 
    <div class="todo">
        <ul class="notcompleted" id="listnode">
        <h3>Planned Tasks</h3>
        <li>Write Down Tasks
            <span class="option3"><button style="width: 3.5px; height: 15px;" class="boton1" id="delete" onclick="DelTask()"><span class="no-incomplete"></span></button></span>
            <span class="option4"><button style="width: 3.5px; height: 15px;" class="boton2" id="checkmark" onclick="makecomplete()"><span class="yes-incomplete">✔️</span></button></span>
        </li>    
    </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="done">
        <ul class="completed" id="acceptednodes">
            <h3>Completed Tasks</h3>
            <li>Tasks
                <span class="option1"><button style="width: 3.5px; height: 15px;" class="boton3" id="crossover"><span class="x-complete" data-crossover>✖</span></button></span>             
   <span class="option2"><button style="width: 3.5px; height: 15px;" class="boton4" id="delete"><span class="no-complete"></span></button></span>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <span class="estate">
        <textarea rows="30" cols="130" placeholder="Free Real Estate" spellcheck="false" style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></textarea>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function addLi()
{

    var input = document.getElementById('texter').value,
        list = document.getElementById('listnode'),
        listeditem = document.createElement("LI"),
        textitem = document.createTextNode(input),
        delbutton = document.createElement('delete'),
        checkbutton = document.createElement('checkmark')

        delbutton.innerHTML = '<span class="option3"><button style="width: 3.5px; height: 15px;" class="boton1" id="delete" ><span class="no-incomplete" onclick="DelTask"></span></button></span>'
        checkbutton.innerHTML = '<span class="option4"><button style="width: 3.5px; height: 15px;" class="boton2" id="checkmark" ><span class="yes-incomplete">✔️</span></button></span>'

     listeditem.appendChild(textitem);
     list.appendChild(listeditem);
     listeditem.appendChild(delbutton);
     listeditem.appendChild(checkbutton);

}
```

How the website design looks:

[image]

Comment: `onclick="DelTask"` would have to be `onclick="DelTask()"`, but I would suggest to use `.addEventListener()` instead. With that this would be the clicked `<button>`. From there you can traverse the DOM up until you find the `<li>` for the task and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `addLi` function, add the following:

```js
delbutton.addEventListener('click', () => list.removeChild(listeditem));
```

When the `delbutton` is clicked, this will remove the list item from the list using [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of the function `addLi`:

```
delbutton.onclick = function() { listeditem.remove() };
```